# Instance variable to stop a running thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading

Header :

```
@interface CodeTest : NSObject {
BOOL cancelThread;
}

-(void) testCode;
-(void) stopRunning;
-(void) startRunning;

@property (assign) BOOL cancelThread;
@end
```

Implementation :

```
-(void)stopRunning{
    self.cancelThread = YES;
}

-(void)startRunning{
    self.cancelThread = NO;

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(testCode) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

}
-(void)testCode{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"STARTED");
    /* Std C99 code */
    while( conditions ){
            if(self.cancelThread){
                 conditions = NO;
            }
            ...
            ...
    }
    /* end of C code */
    [pool release];
}
```

As you can see, it tires to execute testCode on a separate thread and using the cancelThread BOOL as a stop execution flag in the separate thread.

I have the following issue :

- The compiler signals that `self.cancelThread` in the middle of the std c code is not valid (self is not defined). I think, it tries to interpret that statement as c code but this is obj-c.

There is something missing ?

UPDATE : It's not related to missing {}'s as one of you suggested... The code works perfectly without the `if(self.cancelThread){ conditions = NO; }`.

Comment: you don't get warnings at `@property (assign) BOOL cancelThread;` ?  I don't think is the solution to this but you need `@property(nonatomic) BOOL cancelThread`  and set your autorelease pool inside `testCode `method. (not wrapping the NSThread call)

Comment: @nacho4d actually, you probably *don't* want "nonatomic" in this case, because the value is being set/checked by multiple threads. You're correct about doing the autorelease pool inside the `testCode` method.

Comment: Thanks I've modified the autorelease pool as you said !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> -[CodeTest setCancelThread:]: unrecognized selector.

Means that you don't have a setter defined for the `cancelThread` property. You're missing

```
@synthesize cancelThread;
```

(in your `@implementation` section)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "    /* Std C99 code */"?

If that code is really being compiled as C99 code, then `self.cancelThread` is problematic because it is an Objective-C expression.  First, it is the equivalent of `[self cancelThread], a method call and, secondly, it requires`self` which wouldn't be present in the body of a C99 function.

However, given that the code you showed has it in a method, the comment doesn't make sense.